# Need Help on modeling Database Structure (SQL or Django)

Tags: sql, database, database-design

This is not a total query question I need small help regarding how do I model or save my data to compare with existing database.

I am scraping certain about 200 rows of database every 10 mins which is stock related database.
suppose

```
company  A price at 12 pm was 1500 
company A price at 12:10 became 1560.
```

shall I save these both database and compare based on latest 2 entries and set the message that you made 60 point profit as of now untill 12:18 pm and again save 12:20 pm database and compare this with 12:10 pm database?
I hope I am able to state my problem well any misunderstanding will reply on comment Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
company
________
company_id
ticker
name 
etc

stock_price
_____________
ticker
price_date
price
```